# Uploading multiple files - Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file-upload

```
include "host.php";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$size = $_FILES["files"]["size"];
$type = $_FILES["files"]["type"];
$error = $_FILES["files"]["error"];
$lista = $_FILES["files"]["name"];

foreach ($lista as $nome_immagine) {
   $file = basename($nome_immagine);
   $uploadfile = "photo1/$file";
   echo $uploadfile;
   $temp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO prova (gruppo, img) VALUES ('$name', '$file')") or die(mysql_error());
    move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadfile);
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
}

### Chiudiamo il Database ###
mysql_close($conn_host);
```

This is a uploading multiple files.
Give me this error:

Notice: Array to string conversion in...

Here: move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadfile);

Why?

Comment: You left out the most useful bit: the error message. What line? What variable?

Comment: Sorry, this "move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadfile);"

Answer (score 0):

Since you're uploading multiple files, `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"]` is an array, so you need to index it just like all the other `$_FILES` elements.

```
foreach ($lista as $index => $nome_immagine) {
    $file = basename($nome_immagine);
    $uploadfile = "photo1/$file";
    echo $uploadfile;
    $temp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$index];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO prova (gruppo, img) VALUES ('$name', '$file')") or die(mysql_error());
    move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadfile);
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
}
```